# How can I get value from HTML tag in IOS?

Tags: html, ios, objective-c

I have string coming from webservice and I need to fetch value from HTML tag.

```
<b>Time:</b> Sunday, 17 July 2016 at 18:00<br /><b>Details:</b> Plug in to a regular feast of glorious gospel revelation! / Visit www.TheNewMystics.TV to become a premium member. Each month, John Crowder interacts live with viewers, answering questions, teaching and releasing the glory via live stream. / Members can send in questions live, enjoy each month's broadcast and have access to all archive teachings. / / Starts at 6 p.m. Pacific/ 9 p.m. Eastern<br /><b>Location:</b> www.thenewmystics.tv
```

How can I get value of `Time`, `location` and `details` from `HTML` string

Thanks

Comment: Have you read this document.https://www.raywenderlich.com/14172/how-to-parse-html-on-ios

Comment: It can be easily done by using NSString substring functions too if you don't want to use the above solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `substringWithRange`. Pass HTML tag between two range you will get string between those.

```
NSRange r1 = [s rangeOfString:@"<b>Time:</b>"];
NSRange r2 = [s rangeOfString:@"<br />"];
NSRange rSub = NSMakeRange(r1.location + r1.length, r2.location - r1.location - r1.length);
NSString *sub = [s substringWithRange:rSub];
```

Answer (score 0):

You might can use  [hpple](https://github.com/topfunky/hpple)!

such as:

```
#import "TFHpple.h"

NSData  * data      = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:@"index.html"];

TFHpple * doc       = [[TFHpple alloc] initWithHTMLData:data];
NSArray * elements  = [doc search:@"//a[@class='sponsor']"];

TFHppleElement * element = [elements objectAtIndex:0];
[e text];                       // The text inside the HTML element (the content of the first text node)
[e tagName];                    // "a"
[e attributes];                 // NSDictionary of href, class, id, etc.
[e objectForKey:@"href"];       // Easy access to single attribute
[e firstChildWithTagName:@"b"]; // The first "b" child node
```